# Seq.generate_using is MIA

Tags: f#

I'm trying to use the `Seq.generate_using` function but unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to find it. I thought it would be living here:

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Seq.generate_using
```

But it doesn't. I am getting the error listed below.

> C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\fsharp1\Program.fs(54,63):
>   error FS0039: The value, constructor,
>   namespace or type 'generate_using' is
>   not defined. A construct with this
>   name was found in
>   FSharp.PowerPack.dll, which contains
>   some modules and types that were
>   implicitly referenced in some previous
>   versions of F#. You may need to add an
>   explicit reference to this DLL in
>   order to compile this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Sept 2008 CTP Release Notes](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2008/08/29/detailed-release-notes-for-the-f-september-2008-ctp-release.aspx):

> The F# library is split into two
>   components. FSharp.Core.dll: Contains
>   the core F# libraries, which will be
>   stabilized and versioned infrequently.
>   **FSharp.PowerPack.dll**: Contains
>   additional useful F# libraries and
>   tools which will version more
>   frequently, and allow continued
>   innovation on top of the core F#
>   language and libraries.

Some methods in the Seq module were moved into the FSharp.PowerPack assembly, so you can only get those methods by doing the following:

- If you're using Visual Studio, open your Solution Explorer, right-click on the project file, choose "Add Reference", and add "FSharp.PowerPack.dll".
- If you're using a script file or fsi, then type **`#r "FSharp.PowerPack";;`** to load the assembly.

Now you should be able to call Seq.generate_using.

Answer (score 0):

The #r "FSharp.PowerPack";; works for me but the addition of PowerPack to my solution does not. I am trying to use HashSet<>.

Comment: Using the answer provided in the following link by dsyme, I know that I've been missing the fact that FSI works (mostly) independent of the project:

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/7031.aspx

That is, although I had added FSharp.PowerPack.dll to my project, FSI was still rejecting the following line:

let bestPics = new HashSet<string>()

whereas my project was successfully built.